Are there any primes that satisfy the third iteration of this process?
OEIS sequence $\text{A}092738$ lists primes that can be represented as the sum of two consecutive primes, plus $1$. This process can be iterated; if we call these numbers "sprimes" (summed primes), we can find primes that can be represented as the sum of two consecutive sprimes (not necessarily consecutive primes), plus $1$. Calling these "sprimes$_2$", we can then find primes that can be represented as the sum of two consecutive sprimes$_2$, plus $1$. These would be called sprime$_3$'s, and we can continue iterating this process. As an example, $373 = 173 + 199 + 1 = (83 + 89 + 1) + (97 + 101 + 1) + 1$, therefore $373$ is a sprime$_2$.
I wrote a Python program to seek out these numbers. Upon testing numbers up to four million, it found many sprimes and sprimes$_2$, but not one sprime$_3$. My question is thus:

Is it possible to prove that there are no sprimes$_3$? If there are sprimes$_3$, what about sprimes$_4$? Sprimes$_5$? Sprimes$_n$?

To be clear, I'm looking for a rigorous way to show that either there are or there aren't sprimes$_n$ (where $n$ is $3$ for my first question). Thanks for your assistance!

What do you mean by "two consecutive sprimes"? The natural interpretation would be "two consecutive terms of A092738", but from the example given, perhaps you actually mean "two consecutive primes that happen to both be sprimes".

@EspeciallyLime: Yes, the example is perhaps not as general as it should be, but I think the intent is clear: the OP says explicitly "two consecutive sprimes".

@TonyK that's what I initially thought too, but that interpretation seems to give some small examples of sprime$_3$s

@EspeciallyLime: Oh, I see what you mean! I found $5705$ of them less than 2 billion, of which the smallest is $106261$. OP, please clarify!

Two consecutive sprimes indeed does mean two consecutive terms in the sequence of sprimes, not two consecutive primes that happen to be primes -- sorry for the confusion!

@TonyK I don't think $547$ and $1031$ are consecutive sprime$_2$s; in between them there's $727 = 353 + 373 + 1$.

I agree there seem to be more sprime$_3$s though. E.g., from just the sprime$_2$s observed above, $1759 = 727 + 1031 + 1$.

Huh! There must be a bug in my program, as
$$1759 = 727 + 1031 + 1 = (353 + 373 + 1) + (509 + 521 + 1) + 1 = ((173 + 179 + 1) + (181 + 191 + 1) + 1) + ((251 + 257 + 1) + (257 + 263 + 1) + 1)$$
(as @JakobStreipel helpfully pointed out). Working on that now...

Oh, I see... because $727$ and $1031$ aren't consecutive primes, my program wasn't catching $1759$ as a possible sprime$3$. This brings up the same question about the definition of sprime$n$ -- does it mean "a number that is the sum of two consecutive primes that are also sprimes${n-1}$ (plus $1$)", or does it mean "a number that is the sum of two consecutive sprimes${n-1}$ that are not necessarily consecutive primes (plus $1$)". Under the former definition, $1759$ is the smallest sprime$_3$, and under the latter definition, $31571389$ is the smallest sprime$_3$.

I think it should be the former definition (in which case $1759$ is the smallest), but I'd love to hear the community's thoughts on this...

@JakobStreipel: Yes, you are right. My latest program correctly spits out $1759$ (not $1579$).

The smallest sprime$_3$ is
\begin{align*}
31571389&=15785689+15785699+1\\
&=(7892831+7892849+1)+(7892849+7892873+1)+1
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
7892831&=3946403+3946421+1\\
7892849&=3946421+3946427+1\\
7892873&=3946429+3946447+1.
\end{align*}
I didn't do a full analysis, but I think the size of this first example is roughly consistent with a probabilistic heuristic. I would conjecture that there are infinitely many sprime$_n$s for every $n$.

Thanks for the response! Good to know that there's a sprime$_3$ -- now what we're looking for is a rigorous way to show that there are infinitely many sprime$_n$s for all $n\ge 1$. I can't think how to go about that, though...
